# Send Multiple HTTP Request with Axios

Tags: node.js, axios, http-headers, httprequest

I am trying to crawl this website to get university names using Node JS Axios. I notice that the website uses Paginated API so to crawl all the university name I have to send multiple requests.

```
const url = 'https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/search?_sort=rank&_sortDirection=asc&study=Engineering&_mode=table&_page=1;
const url = 'https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/search?_sort=rank&_sortDirection=asc&study=Engineering&_mode=table&_page=2;
const url = 'https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/search?_sort=rank&_sortDirection=asc&study=Engineering&_mode=table&_page=3;
...
const url = 'https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/search?_sort=rank&_sortDirection=asc&study=Engineering&_mode=table&_page=55;
```

I have written code to crawl only one page. I do not know how to crawl more than 1 page. 
Here is my code

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');
fs = require('fs');

_sort=rank&_sortDirection=asc&study=Engineering";
// table view
page= 1;
const url = 'https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/search?_sort=rank&_sortDirection=asc&study=Engineering&_mode=table&_page=' +page;

fetchData(url).then((res) => {
    const html = res.data;
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const unilist = $('.TableTabular__TableContainer-febmbj-0.guaRKP > tbody > tr >td ');

    unilist.each(function() {

        let title = $(this).find('div').attr("name");

        if (typeof(title) == 'string') {
            console.log(title);
            fs.appendFileSync('universityRanking.txt', title+'\n', function (err) {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
              });

            } 

    });
})


async function fetchData(url){

    console.log("Crawling data...")

    // make http call to url
    let response = await axios(url).catch((err) => console.log(err));

    if(response.status !== 200){
        console.log("Error occurred while fetching data");
        return;
    }
    return response;

}
```

I would like help on how to make 55 Axios requests? I checked that the page has 55 pages. I need to append all the university name from each page to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

The `axios.all()` method can help your use case.

```js
axios.all([])   // Pass the array of axios requests for all the 55 pages here
  .then({
    // Multiple requests complete
  });
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot. Where exactly so I make the HTTP request ?

Comment: You need to change your ```fetchData()``` method accordingly.